# Why is it giving me TypeError: Expected cv::UMat for argument 'src'?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I am finding trouble with some code that I  am writing for homework.
I think that `mask = source[B-R].point(lambda i: i < -26)` can't be assigned to the function `cv2.dilate(mask, kernel,iterations=1)`
I will post the photo of the code

```
import PIL
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import cv2

image = cv2.imread ('/Applications/Python 3.7/Input/1.jpg', 0)
image = Image.open ('/Applications/Python 3.7/Input/1.jpg')

source = image.split()
R, G, B = 0, 1, 2   

mask = source[B-R].point(lambda i: i < -26)  

kernel = np.ones((9, 9))
mask = cv2.dilate(mask, kernel, iterations=1)
```

Answer (score 2):

Your masks needs to be of type UMat. Your image is some kind of PIL Image format. The original image is:

```
print(image.format)
JPEG
```

and your mask is of type:

```
print(mask.format)
None
```

You are also not using the image you read with `cv.imread`

You can create a simple mask using opencv e.g. something like this:

```
b,g,r = cv2.split(image)
res = b-r
ret = res[res<26]
mask = cv2.dilate(ret, kernel, iterations=1)
```

Comment: "Your masks needs to be of type UMat." -- not necessarily, that's only if you want to use the Transparent API. More commonly, it's a numpy array, just like in your example code.

Comment: You will need to read it without the `0` at the end so it will be color not grayscale. ```image = cv2.imread ('/Applications/Python 3.7/Input/1.jpg')```

Comment: Julian thanks for your help. I have some questions for you to ask in private. This is my email: alesalvini@gmail.com please text me